# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' using Subprocess python

Tags: python, subprocess, typeerror

Good morning. I'm trying to apply this code but I receive the message "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'".

```
import subprocess as Popen
import subprocess as sp

prog = sp.Popen(['runas', '/noprofile', '/user:Administrator', 'NeedsAdminPrivilege.exe'],stdin=sp.PIPE)
prog.stdin.write('password')
prog.communicate()
```

but I receive the message "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'".

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "runas.py", line 6, in <module>
    prog.stdin.write(Pswd) TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' ser: ssword for domain
```

I'm new using Python and had several days trying to solve this.

I already tried to use .encode() but I'm not sure how to use it. I tried to change the "Password" string with a Variable without any success too.

I really appreciate your expertise.

Best Regards,

Edit:

I correct the code to your suggestion:

```
    import subprocess as Popen
import subprocess as sp

pswd="P4ssW0rd"
prog = sp.Popen(['runas', '/noprofile', '/user:domain\romanuser', cmd.exe'],stdin=sp.PIPE)
prog.stdin.write(pswd.encode() )
prog.communicate()
```

And now I receive back:

```
omanuser: ssword for domain
RUNAS ERROR: Unable to acquire user password
```

Comment: Try `prog.stdin.write(b'password')`. The subprocess's standard input likely expects bytes, rather than strings.

Comment: Any string literal can instead be a bytes literal if you precede it by the letter `b`. E.g. `b'password'`.

Comment: Unluckily both comments are not going to help since the code does not match the traceback and there's a variable in place of the string. Always make sure the traceback is from the code you post!

Comment: Thank you very much for all your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should encode the string before you write it.

```
prog.stdin.write('password'.encode())
```

Will do the job.
If it is a variable containing a string, like `Pswd`, you can use `Pswd.encode()`

Comment: That function solve the "TypeError" but my code still not working:

Comment: Post another question with the new error, @RonyChamorro